# Protocol buffer and OO design

Tags: oop, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol buffer as a wire data-format in a client-server architecture. Domain objects (java beans) will go through following life-cycle.

1. Used in client side business logic
2. Converted to protobuf format
3. Transmitted to the server
4. Converted back to domain object
5. Used in server side business logic

["Protocol Buffers and O-O Design"](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) section in ProtoBuf documentation recommends wrapping generated class inside proper domain model.

I'd like to find-out the best appoach.

For e.g. I have a simple proto definition.

```
package customer;

option java_package = "com.example";
option java_outer_classname = "CustomerProtos";

message Customer {
    required string name = 1;
    optional string address = 2;
}
```

This is how domain model is defined. As you can see, the data is completely stored in proto builder object.

```
package com.example;

public class CustomerModel
{
    private CustomerProtos.Customer.Builder builder = CustomerProtos.Customer.newBuilder();

    public String getName()
    {
        return builder.getName();
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        builder.setName(name);
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return builder.getAddress();
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        builder.setAddress(address);
    }

    public byte[] serialize()
    {
        return builder.build().toByteArray();
    }

}
```

Is this a good practice? because these objects are used in all phases of life-cycle, but we only requires protocolbuf format at client-server transmission phase.

Is there any performance issue when accessing proto builder class getter/setter methods specially when proto definition is complex and nested?

Comment: did you found a good practice for this question (proto vs OO)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have no experience with protocol buffers, but I would *not* recommend implementing your domain objects tailored to a specific serialization/transfer framework. You might regret that in the future.

The domain objects and logic of a software application should be as independent as possible from specific implementation issues (in your case serialization/transfer), because you want your domain to be easy to understand and be reusable/maintainable in the future.

If you want to define your domain objects independent of serialization/transfer, you have two options:

1. Before serialization/transfer, you copy the information to protocol
   buffers specific objects and send them to your server. There you
   would have to copy the information back to your domain objects.
2. Use a non-protocol serialization library like [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) or
   [ProtoStuff](http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/) to directly transfer your domain objects to the
   server.

The disadvantages of option 1 are that your domain is defined two times (which is undesirable with respect to modifications) and the copying of information (which produces error-prone and non maintainable code).

The disadvantages of option 2 are that you lose [schema evolution](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2012/12/05/schema-evolution-in-avro-protocol-buffers-thrift.html) (although ProtoStuff apparently [supports it](http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/wiki/ProtostuffRuntime)) and the complete (potentially large) object graph is serialized and transferred. Although you could prune the object graph (manually or with [JGT](http://jgt.sourceforge.net/)) before serialization/transfer.

Comment: Totally agreed @Barry. It gets messy very soon if the same protobuf generated pojos are used as domian objects into building logic. As suggested, its basically only for the easy service-service communication, irrespective of language and nothing more. There are solutions like wrapper, but imgine wrapper for each protobuf object, which is a total mess. From my opinion, its better to have converter utils for every proto or use any mapper library if any.

Answer (score 4):

We've made a [protobuf-converter](https://github.com/BAData/protobuf-converter) to solve the problem of transformation of your Domain Model Objects into Google Protobuf Messages and vice versa.

**How to use it:**

Domain model classes that have to be transformed into protobuf messages must satisfy conditions:

- Class has to be marked by *@ProtoClass* annotaion that contains
  reference on related protobuf message class.
- Class fields has to be marked by *@ProtoField* annotaion. These fields must have getters and setters.

E.g.:

```
@ProtoClass(ProtobufUser.class)
public class User {

    @ProtoField
    private String name;
    @ProtoField
    private String password;

    // getters and setters for 'name' and 'password' fields
    ...
}
```

Code for conversion User instance into related protobuf message:

```
User userDomain = new User();
...
ProtobufUser userProto = Converter.create().toProtobuf(ProtobufUser.class, userDomain);
```

Code for backward conversion:

```
User userDomain = Converter.create().toDomain(User.class, userProto);
```

Conversion of lists of objects is similar to single object conversion.

Comment: Is there a equivalent solution for Dart Lang? Or, any new best practices emergied to convert message/domain object and vice-versa?