# How to implement Protocol Buffer generated code with Object Oriented Design?

Tags: java, oop, serialization, design-patterns, protocol-buffers

I have a question about the general case of implementing functionality regarding generated code/classes from Protocol buffers. General in the sense that, the problem that I am having is in Java right now, but the question is applicable to object-oriented programming as a whole...

Basically, the way that serialization and deserialization would work for my project normally is that I would write custom serializers and deserializers for json for each language that I'm working in, and these would covert json messages into classes that have fields from the json, but with custom methods that I write.

Using protocol buffers gives me a number of advantages, but one important one in my mind is that the automatically generated code means **I am not having to write serializers and deserializers manually**. However, it is unclear what the proper way is to implement logic that involves this deserialized data. The official tutorial (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#parsing-and-serialization) warns against using inheritance for a situation like this:

> Protocol buffer classes are basically data holders (like structs in C) that don't provide additional functionality; they don't make good first class citizens in an object model. If you want to add richer behavior to a generated class, the best way to do this is to wrap the generated protocol buffer class in an application-specific class. Wrapping protocol buffers is also a good idea if you don't have control over the design of the `.proto` file (if, say, you're reusing one from another project). In that case, you can use the wrapper class to craft an interface better suited to the unique environment of your application: hiding some data and methods, exposing convenience functions, etc. **You should never add behavior to the generated classes by inheriting from them**. This will break internal mechanisms and is not good object-oriented practice anyway.

But I'm not sure what is supposed to be done instead...

My options appear to be:

- **Ignoring this warning and creating a class for inheritance anyways.** This means modifying the automatically created protobuf code which I don't want to do, or as in this post (https://blog.teamdev.com/protobuf-serialization-and-beyond-part-3-value-objects-e3dc7b935ac), using a protoc plugin to automatically add this inheritance structure to the automatically generated types. A closed Github issue on protobuf (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4481) talks about problems with this solution as well - although technically supported, the use of plugins is not well documented or supported and still goes against the warning from the tutorial. There may be some kind of casting wizardry I can do to have this work without modifying the generated protobuf code, but I'm not sure... This method seems to make the system easiest to change, as it is automatically responsive to changes in the underlying schema - only methods that serve a proper function (not getters and setters) would be written by me, and would throw compile-time exceptions if their underlying fields no longer work, making sure I make changes to only application code when my schema changes (exactly what I want).
- **Creating a wrapper class as suggested in the above warning, encapsulating the generated code.** This follows the delegation design pattern, which to my understanding is not easily implemented in every language. In Java, for example, the delegation must be written manually and must be changed in code every time the protobuf schema changes, which is obviously not ideal, and I'm not sure how I would implement the Decorator/ Adapter patterns that I'm looking for without inheritance (see first point) or code duplication because of this. This also gets pretty wild as the size of the schema increases, and without an easy way to implement delegation I think this is unsustainable... (This stackoverflow answer and the comment below basically explains what my concern with this method is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16360532/17885960). There is the Lombok delegation class (experimental), and Scala for example supports delegation natively, but I'm not sure this is the best way forward...
- **Not using Protobuf generated classes in domain logic, instead manually creating classes with custom logic and mapping the protobuf messages / generated classes to these custom objects as data enters/leaves the application.** This is basically the same as what happens currently with JSON in the application, except instead of mapping JSON directly, I would be first converting the messages to protobuf generated classes, then coverting these protobuf generated classes into the custom classes. I might be able to get away with using something like gson in Java to handle the automated conversion between these two types (protobuf-generated class -> json -> custom class and vice versa), but this adds overhead to the system which never existed before (instead of just parsing json into a class, I'm parsing json into a class, then that class into another class), and I still won't be benefitting from the automatic methods created by the protobuf generated code. This method is the most serialization-format-agnostic, as the same classes that support json can support protobufs, but this method also seems to need the most boilerplate code out of all the options - I would be duplicating all the getters and setters of the protobuf generated classes, as well as writing domain logic, as well as writing converter classes/methods. This method is suggested in the following threads: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/170822, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16360532/17885960, https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/pABidPhYqIo).

The threads I find on this topic are old and sparse - is this a rare problem to have, is it too niche, or am I just overthinking things?

What is the best way forward, and how can I better understand how to think about and solve this kind of problem in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the best way is definitely to wrap the generated class. A .proto file defines the shape of data, and has absolutely nothing whatsoever to say about the logic that should be used for handling that data.

I think I can see what you're getting at, but I think that some of the benefits of that can be achieved in other ways. It's nice to have a single point of truth; a .proto file is a single point of truth for what one's data looks like (every application that uses that data compiles that .proto file), and its would be nice to have a single point of truth for logic too.

One attraction of a single point of truth for  is that, should that need to be changed, the change ripples on outwards. So, if we change a .proto file, applications that use it can simply be recompiled.

**Giving a Hint**

With logic, it's probable that the change in logic has been brought about because of a change in the data, or is associated with data. Whilst we cannot define logic with a .proto file (at least, not in the formal automatic output sense), we can at least make it blindingly obvious that the logic has changed.

For example, suppose we had a message that contained a field called "bearing", and suppose we had written some comment in the .proto file as to how it was to be handled. One way to indicate that there is a change to the logic (that was originally specified in the comment) is to rename the field to "bearingXXX". When a developer tries to compile their app, it will fail because their source code is referencing fields called "bearing", which can no longer be found.

On investigation, they'll end up looking at the .proto file, note that the field is now called "bearingXXX", and hopefully are also noticing the comments in the same part of the file saying a) why the new name, and b) here's the new logic.

Ok, so that's not fully automated changes to the logic, but it is a way of forcing developers to read a change notice. Hopefully, having read it, they will then update their code to implement the new logic, and refer to the field by its new name.

It is also very useful for project managers; change the name of the field, and all the compiler error messages approximate to things impacted, and the amount of work needed to implement the change. It's also a good way of ensuring that no places where change is needed are missed.

That's a half-way house that is language independent.

**Single Language Implementation, Multiple Language Bindings**

Otherwise, I think that if a single definition of the logic is important, and multiple languages are important, one then has to seriously consider shared libraries / DLLs or their equivalents. I know this might make bindings a nuisance to create.

However, there is one thing in one's favour in this. The hardest, most annoying part of language bindings is handling data. However, we have a .proto file for the data. The logic can be implemented so that, instead of taking a whole bunch of method parameters, each method / function simply accepts and returns a byte array. The input byte array a serialised .proto message containing all the method's input parameters. The output array is the serialised output result. In psuedo code:

```
bytes MyMethod(bytes input)
{
    struct Parameters params = Parameters.parse(input)
    struct Results result = new Result();
    <do stuff, populating result>
    return result.SerialiseToByteArray();
}
```

Every method would look something like that, just with different message types for input / output.

The attraction of this approach is that there's only one form of data marshalling to master in creating a language binding, to the point where it's probably easy-ish to autogenerate that, and one is not wasting much time per-language. And you're not having to change that binding, just because the parameter list has changed.

Obviously this isn't exactly the fastest way to get data in and out of a method, but it's the easiest way to create bindings for multiple languages, using a technology (GPB) that's already lurking in the project anyway. And, best of all, by have multiple bindings for a single shared library / DLL, the logic is defined just once (in the source code one has decided to implement the library / DLL in).

This is how DBus solved this problem. Server methods are called by serialising input parameters in a DBus message (defined by a schema), and results are returned in the same way.

**Linking, or Not?**

Obviously then it's a matter of choosing a language that's got the range you want w.r.t. platforms and OS. This is entirely subjective and project specific, but on the whole one feels that it's simplest if the logic library is written in the lowest common denominator. For example, if it's never going to have to be called from C, don't write it in C. This is purely on the assumption that the library / DLL is going to have to be linked into the application.

With DBus, of course one doesn't do that; the application interacts with the method server via pipes to a broker. At some point or other, one ends up seeing why things like Dbus have been created, or COM on Windows, or earlier attempts like Corba.

**Some Logic**

If we extend our gaze beyond proto files towards ASN1,  this allows you to define constraints on value and/or size. This is logic to establish validity of data, and it's useful for such boilerplate code to be autogenerated. XML/XSD can do this too (but it's hard to find tools that implement it properly), as can JSON schemas.

ASN.1 in particular is very good for this. It's complex for the compiler writers to fully implement ASN.1, but the end result for system developers is very good. A lot of the work of interface validation is checking that values are within range, and lists are the right length. To have that done automatically, in every language, just check the return error code from the serialiser / deserialiser, takes a lot of coding and review time out of a project. Code time is reduced, because the developer need only handle the return code. Review time is reduced, because the reviewer need check only for that. And ASN.1 constraints can get very elaborate - you can mix them up with logic (unions of constraints), lists, even regular expressions. They can even be left open ended, subject to future change. The complexity behind this is why good ASN.1 tools cost money - it's a fairly big project to implement a compiler. There's some reasonable open source partial implementations, but the commercial tools are very impressive in their language coverage and the degree of completion of the ASN.1 standards.

I just wished Google Protocol Buffers also did constraints, even simple ones. It doesn't change wireformat and could be made optional in the compiler, so it's not a breaking change for code or data.